# Convert old DNS zone file into new format

Tags: text-processing, dns

I've got this old domain zone file with this format

```
ZZYZX IN NS DNS1.NAME-SERVICES.COM. 
        IN NS DNS2.NAME-SERVICES.COM. 
        IN NS DNS3.NAME-SERVICES.COM.   
        IN NS DNS4.NAME-SERVICES.COM.  
ZZYZXX IN NS NS.HOSTDEZINA.COM. 
        IN NS NS2.HOSTDEZINA.COM.  
...
```

I want to convert it like so

```
ZZYZX IN NS DNS1.NAME-SERVICES.COM. 
ZZYZX IN NS DNS2.NAME-SERVICES.COM. 
ZZYZX IN NS DNS3.NAME-SERVICES.COM.   
ZZYZX IN NS DNS4.NAME-SERVICES.COM.  
ZZYZXX IN NS NS.HOSTDEZINA.COM. 
ZZYZXX IN NS NS2.HOSTDEZINA.COM.  
...
```

Is there any easy way to do it? Probably some linux command line tool? I can write script to do this, but I'm afraid I can make lots of mistakes. The file is around 20MB and I can't do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'NF>3{x=$1} NF<=3{$1=x" "$1}1' file
```

- If the number of fields is greater than 3 then save the first field value (`$1`) in the variable `x`.
- If the number of fields is lower of equal to 3 then prepend the value of `x` to the first field of the line.

Ouput:

```
ZZYZX IN NS DNS1.NAME-SERVICES.COM.
ZZYZX IN NS DNS2.NAME-SERVICES.COM.
ZZYZX IN NS DNS3.NAME-SERVICES.COM.
ZZYZX IN NS DNS4.NAME-SERVICES.COM.
ZZYZXX IN NS NS.HOSTDEZINA.COM.
ZZYZXX IN NS NS2.HOSTDEZINA.COM.
```